# UI compatibility across all BlackBerry devices

Tags: blackberry

I wrote a simple app for the BlackBerry and tested with the 9630 simulator.
How do I get a UI design that is compatible with all the simulators?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your UI has to make as little assumptions as possible on things like display size, physical keyboard etc.  On touchscreen devices the screen size actually "changes" when the device is rotated.  And to second @Michael, testing, testing, testing :)

Answer (score 7):

testing, testing, and testing

If you need your app to work on all the simulators, then get all the simulators and try it.
RIM [does a pretty good job](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/resources/simulators.jsp) of making simulators available to you for a variety of devices.

Comment: This is true, but also, remember that you can make use of things like getPreferredWidth() to have display fields span across the width of the screen and not some static pixel dimension. If the concern is not so much in display, but interface interaction, like touch screen vs trackball, then all I can suggest is a book like "Beginning BlackBerry Development" available through Apress... Or perhaps you can refine your question to be more specific.