# Tricks to run my blackberry app in multiple screens

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

Is there any trick so that i can run my blacberry app in different screen sizes and resolutions..i am using eclipse with blackberry plugin..

Comment: possible duplicate of [UI compatibility across all BlackBerry devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066784/ui-compatibility-across-all-blackberry-devices)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install more BB smartphone simulators and test your application on them.

Here is the link: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/subcategories/?userType=21&category=BlackBerry+Smartphone+Simulator